# how to create a tableview pop up for two buttons using one tableviewcontroller class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a button, when i click on a button table pop up appears Which i have already done.

for my application i have two buttons in a view  for example "country" button  and "state" button.

When i click on country button country list should appear in a "table pop up"  and when i click on a state button state list should appear in "table pop up".

So how do we do this by using one tableView controller class.

Please provide me with sample code.

presently for single button i am using below code with one tableviewcontroller class. i want for two buttons with different data list in it with single tableviewController class

```
-(IBAction) button:(id) sender{

NSLog(@"Go");

if (self.popoverController == nil)

{
    PopOver *lang = [[PopOver alloc]
                   initWithNibName:@"PopOver" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    UIPopoverController *popOver = 
    [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:lang];

    popOver.delegate = self;
    [lang release];

    self.popoverController = popOver;
    [popOver release];
}

[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 100)];

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

**TableViewController class**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

languages = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];
[languages addObject:@"English"];
[languages addObject:@"korean"];

[super viewDidLoad];
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the data for your tableview is stored in an array. You can have the buttons actions populate the tableview's array with either country or state information, based on which button was pressed. That's probably the easiest way to do it unless the structure of the tableviews is different for the two options.

Comment: ya data for tableView is stored in an array.AS i have two button how do we store data for countries and state in a array.for one button i have showed in the above code.NOTE i have edited my code.so please tel me with some sample how can i do that.